# Regex for searching for 2 consecutive letters that are in a specific location

Tags: javascript, regex

So I am trying to create a regex search for one word with a length of AT LEAST 4 and has 2 consecutive letters after the first letter. So for example:

```
poop = match  
pee = no match
marshmallow = no match
lop = no match
application = match
droop = no match
```

I have tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work: `^([A-za-z]([A-Za-z]){2})`

My thought process was start character followed by the `[A-Za-z]{2}` which would mean exactly two consecutively? I am not sure how to do quantity limits without maybe adding additional repeating `[A-Za-z]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
/^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z])\1[a-zA-Z]+$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1XEJ8v/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]` - a letter
- `([a-zA-Z])` - Group 1: a letter
- `\1` - the same letter as in Group 1
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - one or more letters
- `$` - end of string.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const words = ['poop', 'pee', 'marshmallow', 'lop', 'application', 'droop'];
const rx = /^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z])\1[a-zA-Z]+$/;
for (let word of words) {
  console.log(word, '->', rx.test(word))
}
```

Comment: Thanks I see what I did wrong now. If I wanted to limit the word to a specific length would I just change the `[a-zA-Z]+` at the end to `[a-zA-z]{10}` (if I wanted to say make the word length exactly 10)?

Comment: @Joey `^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z])\1` already matches 3 letters. If the overall word should be exactly 10 letters, you should use `[a-zA-Z]{7}` at the end. Note `A-Z`, not `A-z`.

Comment: I've not got a reply back from OP as yet, but we may or may not need case-insensitive matching to allow for `'peEp'` and the likes.

Comment: @JvdV That is so minor a problem, `/i` flag solves it.